# Cassandra : Inserting empty values for float datatype in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

i have defined 5 columns in cassandra.
for suppose (emp_name, emp_dept, emp_location, emp_bonus, emp_hike)

4th and 5th columns are float type

when I'm inserting a record which has only three values 
suppose 
('paul', 'sales', 'Detroit', , )

I'm getting this exception
Failed to import 3638 rows: ParseError - could not convert string to float: ,  given up without retries

how to insert empty records to float datatype ??

Comment: Can your 4th and 5th columns accept a null value?

Comment: yes it does. We have a csv file that need to imported into a table but few columns does not have a value.... but when i give text instead of float it works fine.. I need to take the data type as float

Comment: If using COPY command use `with NULL=0` OR `with NULL=NULL` . By default nulls are converted to string in COPY command